# Can we stop while function with a string?

Tags: c

I'm amateur on programming I'm trying things that I feel interest in while learning.So I wanted to see if I can "check" the user entered the word I wanted for continue using the program or not but I can't seem to find an answer to this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void digit_check( float n )
{
    printf("Please enter a number:");
    scanf("%f",&n);
    printf("\n");
    if(n >= 10 && n < 100)
    {
        printf("The number you entered is 2 digit.\n");
    }
    else if(n < 10)
    {
        printf("The number you entered is 1 digit.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The number you entered is more than 2 digit.\n");
    }
}
int main()
{
float n;
char answer[5];
char str1[5];
int cmp = 1;
while(cmp = 1)
{
   printf("Do you want to continue?");
   scanf("%s",answer);
   strcpy(str1, "Yes");
   cmp = strcmp(answer,str1);
   if(cmp = 1)
   {
      digit_check(n);
   }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: If answer is not "yes" then use break to exit the while loop. PS (cmp = 1) should read (cmp == 1). Assignment uses a single equals, but equality tests require double equals.

Comment: Enable compiler warnings, the problem will be evident...

Comment: Note that you pass an uninitialized value to `digit_check()` that is completely ignored — the `scanf()` in the function overwrites the value passed unless the conversion fails completely (for example, if the next input character is a letter instead of part of a number).  You might also notice that your code deems -1,000,000.00 as being a 1-digit number, which isn't the usual definition of a 1-digit number.  You are also at risk of overflowing your arrays; if the user types `catastrophic-failure` instead of 'Yes' or 'No', you probably get a catastrophic failure (or other undefined behaviour).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for pointing it out I found the solution with checking it like  if((10 <= n && n < 100)||((-10 >= n && n > -100)) and else if(n < 10 && n > -10)

Comment: The `fabs()` function from `<math.h>` (contrasted with the `abs()` function from `<stdlib.h>`) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strcmp returns 0 when two strings are equal, and you compare it with 1.

```
cmp = strcmp(answer,str1);
if(cmp = 1)
```

in addition, the statement

```
   if(cmp = 1)
```

is doing assignment of the value 1 to cmp variable.

the correct condition shall be

```
       if(cmp == 0)
```

e.g. use **==** (double '=' sign) to check equality and not single '=' sign which is doing assignment.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` returns zero if both the `strings` are equal. You could do as below.

```
printf("Do you want to continue?");
scanf("%s",&answer);

while(strcmp(answer,"yes") == 0)
{
   digit_check(n);
   printf("Do you want to continue?");
   scanf("%s",&answer);
}
```

Comment: @EnesCeylan You don't need to pass `n` as parameter to `digit_check`. Just declare local variable in `digit_check`

Comment: Shouldn't it be like while(strcmp(answer,"yes") == 1) since we're trying to check if it's same and we want it to work if it's true.Or is it like 0 = TRUE and 1 = FALSE? Edit : when I use while(strcmp(answer,"yes") == 1) it works with "yes" but not "Yes" or anything else

Comment: strcmp will return zero if both strings are same, ie out of strcmp will be 0. So you will be comparing 0 == 0 which is TRUE.

Comment: Thank you!I thought it was like 1 = same 0 = different.